# Cannot import variable from script in Python

Tags: python

Python newbie here. Let's say I have two Python scripts main.py and lib.py. There is a variable (not a function) in lib.py that I want to use in main.py. I imported lib.py in main.py and called lib.variable.
I still receive the classical import error ('module' has no attribute called 'variable') and I don't get why. Both files remain in the same directory and I triple ckecked for typo. I also tried the 'from lib import variable' command, with no results.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Print your code, it will be much faster.

Comment: Alright folks, 

I fixed this. Both files were calling on each other!  main.py was importing lib.py (where variable was called) before variable was defined in main.py


Take home message : always import stuff properly.

Comment: Take home message:  post your code!  You would probably have realised the issue when constructing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me.  Here's how:

lib.py:

```
variable = 42
```

main.py:

```
import lib

print lib.variable
```

Another version of main.py:

```
from lib import variable

print variable
```

You don't show your code, so any other hints would be a guess.  One guess might be that you have another module called `lib.py` that is being loaded instead.

Note that `import` names are case-sensitive, even on Windows.

Comment: PEP-8 says "modules all lowercase":

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names

Comment: @xbello:  Doh!  post changed.

Comment: Got this error: No module named '__main__.<filename>

I just have a collection of python files and want to import a variable from one file into other.

Comment: @saran3h: create a new question, post a minimal amount of code to reproduce the problem, and the full error trace.  It sounds like your `import` is wrong, but that's a guess.

Answer (score 0):

This is a blind bet (post some code!), but if you imported lib.py, try importing just lib (without .py).